# How to assign different values to a list of strings using numbers from a data frame?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dictionary, assign

I am trying to assign masses of a list of peptides by adding together the masses of single amino acids.

For example, I have a vactorlike below:

```
c("AA", "AC", "AD" )
```

And I have a dataframe with values for each letter

```
symbol      mass
1       A  71.03711
2       D 115.02694
3       C 103.00919
```

how can I calculate the values for "AA", "AC" and "AD", which should be adding the mass values for each of them together. For example, "AA" should be 71.03711+71.03711=142.07422.
I want my result as this and can be exported as a csv file with two columns:

```
peptide      mass
1       AA  142.07422
2       AC   174.0463
3       AD  186.06405
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe is called `df` and vector as `peptide` you can split individual characters in `peptide`, `match` it with column in dataframe, get corresponding `mass` and `sum` the values. We can put the result in a dataframe.

```
peptide <- c("AA", "AC", "AD" )
mass <- sapply(strsplit(vec, ''), function(x) sum(df$mass[match(x, df$symbol)]))
result <- data.frame(peptide, mass)
result

#  peptide     mass
#1      AA 142.0742
#2      AC 174.0463
#3      AD 186.0641
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse);
symbol <- c("AA", "AC", "AD" )
df <- read.table(text = "symbol      mass
1       A  71.03711
2       D 115.02694
3       C 103.00919")


tibble(symbol) %>% 
   rownames_to_column() %>% 
   separate_rows(symbol, sep="") %>% 
   inner_join(df) %>% 
   group_by(rowname) %>% 
   summarise(symbol = paste(symbol, collapse = ""),
             mass = sum(mass))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  rowname symbol  mass
  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1 1       AA      142.
2 2       AC      174.
3 3       AD      186.
```

Using in `tidyverse` included `purrr`'s `map` and `reduce` function you can try

```
colSums(map(df$symbol,  ~str_count(symbol, .)) %>% reduce(rbind)*df$mass)
[1] 142.0742 174.0463 186.0641
```